# Replace spaces around punctuation in PHP

Tags: php, preg-replace, removing-whitespace

I'm trying to replace trailing spaces around punctuation marks in PHP with matched punctuation followed by a single space.

For example `"Hello  , I am here   ! Not anymore. ..  "` should become `"Hello, I am here! Not anymore... "`. I'm trying to use a regular expressions with a reference

**PHP**

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s*[[:punct:]]\s*/', '$2 ', $string);
```

But the snippet removes punctuations: `"Hello I am here Not anymore"`. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't capture anything and then you try to replace with the second capture group that doesn't exist.  Try a capture group `()` and then use it `$1`:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s*([[:punct:]])\s*/', '$1 ', $string);
```

Comment: This doesn't replace `. .  .  ` by `...`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "Hello  , I am here   ! Not anymore. ..  ";
    echo $string = preg_replace('/(\s*)([[:punct:]])(\s*)/', '$2 ', $string);

?>
```

Output:

```
Hello, I am here! Not anymore. . .
```

Comment: This doesn't replace `. .  .  ` by `...`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to substitute `. .  .` with `...`, this is what I'd do:

```
$string = "Hello  , I am here   ! Not anymore. . .  ";
$string = preg_replace('/\s+(?=\pP)|(?<=\pP\s)\s+/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
Hello, I am here! Not anymore...
```

`\pP` is the unicode property for punctuation, [see the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).
`(?= )` is a positive look ahead
and `(?<= )`a positive look behind, [see the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).